# ASP.NET Web API make request from postman with guid array

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I want to make a request via postman to my ASP.NET Web API action that receives GUID array and I receive this error.

> "The value 'A9980522-344E-4437-98F7-9550695DA768, A1980522-344E-4437-98F7-9550695DA768' is not valid."

This is my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MergeContactsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMergeContactsService _mergeContactsService;

    public MergeContactsController(IMergeContactsService mergeContactsService)
    {
        _mergeContactsService = mergeContactsService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MergeContacts([FromQuery] Guid[] ids)
    {
        await _mergeContactsService.MergeContactsAsync(ids[0], ids[1]);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And this is my request:

> GET https://localhost:7082/api/mergeContacts?ids=A9980522-344E-4437-98F7-9550695DA768, A1980522-344E-4437-98F7-9550695DA768

If someone knows how to fix that I'll be grateful.

Comment: Do get your Array of GUID in MergeContacts api or not???And why you not using post instead of get?

Comment: No, I'm not getting my array.

Comment: This is not the proper way of sending an array over query string. The asp.net model binder does not know how to parse format "{Guid}, {Guid}" into a `Guid[]`. Rather, try to format your query string like so: `/api/mergeContacts?ids={Guid1}&ids={Guid2}`

Answer (score 0):

Try Get Your Ids as `STRING` And Convert to GUID

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MergeContacts([FromQuery] string ids)
        {
            var GuidID = new List<Guid>();
            var AllOfIds = ids.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in AllOfIds)
            {
                GuidID.Add(Guid.Parse(item));   
            }
            return Ok();

        }
```

[image]